# Embedded google map not scrolling in standalone web app

Tags: google-maps, iframe, scroll, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have embedded a google MAP in my standalone web app using an iFrame and it is working as it should except for the fact that when I run the app from the homescreen (= full screen modus) it is impossible to scroll through the map (= touchmove event).

When I touch & hold it is possible to scroll the map but:
- The map gets a blue overlay (to indicate the 'user-select' event)
- The details of the map are not loaded (the position of the maps changes but the new area just stays grey...)

If I launch the app in a normal Safari browser window everything works just fine.

Does anyone have an idea of what might cause this? Any help would be really appreciated.

For your info:
- Moving from an iFrame scenario to a JavaScript version is not the answer I guess, since it is working fine when launched in the browser. It would also require a lot of rework since the the page surrounding the iFrame is already the result of an Ajax call
- I have a similar problem with KoolChart where the charts should be scrollable. On a desktop, it works like a charm. But no way of getting it to work on Mobile.

**UPDATE**
The latest iOS update solved the problem, so issue can be closed :-)

Comment: What are your height and width parameters in your code?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide at least your iframe snippet.